# Silverlight Out of Browser Host

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

What is hosting the Silverlight application when running out of browser?  I can imagine on Windows it uses some very thin IE host but what is it actually running for Windows and Mac machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from hosting in a browser control or window, there's a [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296246(VS.95).aspx) for hosting the Silverlight control, or you could [use the browser plugin APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550717(VS.95).aspx) as well.  I'm not positive on which one the is used for either the Windows or Mac implementations.